# numpy FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in subtract - not reproducible?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm encountering `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in subtract` in a piece of test code.  The exception started being raised without any changes being made in the code itself, so I'm having a great deal of trouble understanding it.

My question: What causes the `invalid value encountered in subtract` exception?  Why would it behave differently on different installs of python+numpy?

DETAILS:

This MWE does *not* raise a `FloatingPointError`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
 '1.6.1'
>>> x = np.arange(5,dtype='float64')
>>> y = np.ones(5,dtype='float64')
>>> x[2]=np.nan
>>> x-y
# array([ -1.,   0.,  nan,   2.,   3.])
```

However, deep within a piece of code, I subtract two `np.float64` `ndarray` objects, and get a floating point exception.  The arrays causing the exception contain some pretty enormous and tiny numbers (e.g., 1e307 and 1e-307) and some `nan`s, but I haven't made any combination of these numbers result in an exception testing on my own.

Much more disturbingly, I have a large grid of Jenkins tests running the exact same code with many versions of numpy, matplotlib, python, and scipy, and NONE of them raise this exception.  I'm lost at this point - I don't know if there is a bug, or if there is, how to track it down.

In case you're morbidly curious, the code in question is [pyspeckit](http://pyspeckit.bitbucket.org) and the test is failing on line 20 of `test_hr2421.py`.

EDIT: Follow-up - I think this little snippet: `np.seterr(invalid='raise')` was being called in a module I was importing, specifically pymc, and a pull request has since prevented this change from being made.

Comment: You can raise the exception doing `np.seterr(invalid='raise');np.array(1e309) - np.array(1e309)` or ignore it setting `invalid='ignore'`. Thus, I'd say that somehow this is changing between versions.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me track it a little further (or at least, pointed me in the right direction).  Now the strangeness is that I'm taking `np.diff(np.array(arr))` (where `arr` is a subclass of `np.ndarray`) and the error (and nan values) occurs in the diff, but not in the input array.

Comment: The array in np.diff, `a=asanyarray(a)` does not equal the input array; it contains NaNs and a variety of values that are tens to hundreds of orders of magnitude different.  I found this out through the interactive debugger.

Comment: What happens if you do `a=array(a, subok=False)`? It won't return your subclass, but does it equal the input array? (Disclaimer: I don't really understand what's happening, these are just things I'd check)

Comment: `np.all(array(arr, subok=False) == array(arr))` is True.  Within `np.diff`, `np.array(a, subok=False) == np.array(a)` is False (not even a vector quantity).  Unfortunately, because of where the Exception is raised, I can't evaluate "a" within `np.diff` before it is set to `a=asanyarray(a)`

Comment: Any further with this? I'm getting this `invalid value` error also, and cannot work out how it comes about: I thought initially it was due to creation of uninitialized arrays (with `ma.masked_all` or directly with `ma.empty`) but after thousands of iterations of these, I cannot get it to fail. I *have*, however, got a MFE using a pickled array with some value that always generates an invalid value error: it shows up a a nan, but it is not. It contains a numpy array of length 1, the single element of which shows up as a nan, but any arithmetic on the whole array (like `arr-1`) raises error.

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I think I just gave up on the whole thing.

Comment: I was getting the same error because I was trying to sum two number of different type: `<type 'numpy.float64'>` and `<type 'mpfr'>` (determined through `type(i)`). Typecasted them to be the same and problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy has configurable behaviour as to how floating point errors are treated.  By default underflow errors are ignored, whereas other errors trigger a warning.  For each category users can change this behaviour with `numpy.seterr`.  These settings are global — there are no namespaces here; so if a library calls `numpy.seterr(all='raise')` then this will affect the entire program until `numpy.seterr` is called again.

You can confirm this is indeed the cause of your problem with

```py
print(numpy.seterr())
```

which should output something like

```
{'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}
```

If some of those categories have the value `raise`, in particular the key `'invalid'`, then that would explain the behaviour you are observing.

You can suppress this exception by calling `numpy.seterr(invalid='warn')`, or, alternatively, `invalid='ignore'`.  For a full list of possible errors, read through the documentation of [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

You can also use a context-manager to temporarily change the behaviour:

```
In [12]: x = np.arange(-5, 5,dtype='float64')

In [13]: with np.errstate(divide="raise"):
    print(1/x)
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-881589fdcb7a> in <module>()
      1 with np.errstate(divide="raise"):
----> 2     print(1/x)
      3 

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

In [14]: with np.errstate(divide="warn"):
    print(1/x)
   ....:     
/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.5/bin/ipython3:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  
[-0.2        -0.25       -0.33333333 -0.5        -1.                 inf
  1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25      ]

In [15]: with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
    print(1/x)
   ....:     
[-0.2        -0.25       -0.33333333 -0.5        -1.                 inf
  1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25      ]
```

I tend to wrap my entire code inside a `with np.errstate(all="raise")` block, and then use a context-manager ignoring a particular condition if I am sure that the problem is not hiding a bug — it usually is, though.

If there was indeed a library changing the state permanently, I would raise an issue with the maintainers or send a pull request, because they really should be using a context manager, so that their changing setting only applies to their block of code and not to the rest of the program.