# Stuck on Value Function Iteration simulation

Tags: python, iteration, simulation, economics

I am trying to simulate a model that solves elastic labor supply in macroeconomics—trying to do it by Value Function Iteration. However, I am getting an error that says

```
runfile('C:/Users/sence/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/sence')
C:\Users\sence\untitled0.py:52: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
      if np.max(np.abs(V - V_new)) < tol:
```

My code is the following.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set parameters
beta = 0.95  # discount factor
rho = 0.1  # utility weight on leisure
alpha = 0.3  # capital share
k_min = 0  # minimum capital level
k_max = 10  # maximum capital level
n_min = 0  # minimum labor supply
n_max = 1  # maximum labor supply
tol = 1e-6  # convergence tolerance

# Define grid over capital
num_points = 100
k_grid = np.linspace(k_min, k_max, num_points)

# Initialize value function
V = np.zeros(num_points)

# Iterate over value function
while True:
    # Initialize value function for this iteration
    V_new = np.zeros(num_points)

    # Iterate over capital levels
    for i, k in enumerate(k_grid[:-1]):
        # Initialize maximum value and optimal labor supply
        max_value = -np.inf
        opt_n = n_min

        # Iterate over labor supply levels
        for n in np.linspace(n_min, n_max, num_points):
            # Compute consumption
            c = k * alpha * n * (1 - alpha) - k_grid[i + 1]

            # Compute value at this point
            if c > 0 and 0 < n < 1:
                value = np.log(c) + rho * np.log(1 - n) + beta * V[i + 1]
            else:
                value = -np.inf

            # Update maximum value and optimal labor supply
            if value > max_value:
                max_value = value
                opt_n = n

        # Update value function for this iteration
        V_new[i] = max_value

    # Check for convergence
    if np.max(np.abs(V - V_new)) < tol:
        break
    else:
        V = V_new

# Compute policy functions
c_policy = k_grid[:-1] * alpha * opt_n * (1 - alpha) - k_grid[1:]
n_policy = opt_n

# Plot policy functions
plt.plot(k_grid, k_grid, 'k--', label='45 degree line')
plt.plot(k_grid[:-1], c_policy, label='Consumption')
plt.plot(k_grid, n_policy, label='Labor supply')
plt.xlabel('Capital')
plt.ylabel('Policy function')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

k_path = [5]  # start at k0 = 5
for t in range(20):
    # Compute consumption
    c = k_path[-1] * alpha * n_policy * (1 - alpha) - k_path[-1]
    k_path.append(k_path[-1] * (1 - n_policy) + c)

plt.plot(k_path)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Capital')
plt.show()
```

I don't know where I made a mistake. I solved the model correctly, and everything should work smoothly, yet I keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated. I am unable to solve it on my own.

Comment: That's a _warning_, not an error

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041982/numpy-floatingpointerror-invalid-value-encountered-in-subtract-not-reproducib